# Command-line Objective-C++ tool has started crashing in [NSApplication sharedApplication]

Tags: objective-c++, core-foundation, nsapplication, cfdictionary, jemalloc

I have [a little CLT](https://github.com/fish2000/subjective-c/tree/master/apps/impaste) for copying and pasting images, written in Objective-C++. Until recently, this program compiled and ran as intended – but only just now, it seems, it has started crashing in the call to `[NSApplication sharedApplication]`.

The stack traces indicate that the crash happens when `NSApplication` initializes an `NSUserDefaults` instance, which ends up calling a `CFDictionary`-related function (i.e. `CFDictionarySetValue`) which then crashes in `free`… but from within `libjemalloc`.

Here’s an example stack trace:

```c
-   Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libjemalloc.2.dylib             0x000000010e7b4ec5 free + 164
1   libjemalloc.2.dylib             0x000000010e7e3d50 zone_free + 168
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffc5a912c5 __CFBasicHashRehash + 3461
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffc5a96927 __CFBasicHashAddValue + 103
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffc5a97a3d CFDictionarySetValue + 221
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffc5c467da __63-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSnapshotSearchList:]_block_invoke + 554
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffc5c4710f -[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchLists:] + 79
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffc5c4655b -[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSnapshotSearchList:] + 155
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffc5ad08bb __CFXPreferencesCopyCurrentApplicationState + 123
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffc5ad04dc _CFLocaleCopyCurrentGuts + 268
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffc5ad0399 +[NSLocale currentLocale] + 9
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffc7508026 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) init] + 1589
12  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffc7507995 +[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) standardUserDefaults] + 81
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffc35c9254 +[NSApplication initialize] + 90
14  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fffda9b0b04 CALLING_SOME_+initialize_METHOD + 19
15  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fffda9a16b9 _class_initialize + 579
16  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fffda9a105b lookUpImpOrForward + 240
17  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fffda9a0ad4 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
18  impaste                         0x0000000106197198 void objc::run_thread<AXDryRunThread>(NSDictionary*) + 120
19  impaste                         0x0000000106196820 main + 2608
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffdb294235 start + 1
```

… This last bit is most curious as I am not using the JeMalloc library. Neither my CLT program nor [the libraries](https://github.com/fish2000/subjective-c) [on which it is built](https://github.com/fish2000/libimread) have anything to do with JeMalloc, and [the build system](https://github.com/fish2000/subjective-c/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) doesn’t currently reference it at all. I don’t include anything from, or link anything to, the JeMalloc library at any point whatsoever.

However: from the stack trace, it looks like the CoreFoundation libraries I am using are, in fact, using JeMalloc.

I don’t know much about JeMalloc, but I do believe that it provides [a global drop-in replacement for `malloc` and `free`](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/blob/dev/include/jemalloc/internal/hooks.h) (in addition to furnishing [a host of custom, fine-grained memory-management functions](http://jemalloc.net/jemalloc.3.html)).

My call to `[NSApplication sharedApplication]` (as seen on line #18 of the stack trace above) looks like this:

```c
template <typename OCThreadType> inline
void run_thread(NSDictionary* options = @{}) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        [[[OCThreadType alloc] initWithOptions:options] start];
        AXAppDelegate* delegate = [[AXAppDelegate alloc] init];
        NSApp.delegate = delegate;
        [NSApp run];
    };
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? What could cause this program to crash in this fashion (and specifically, what may have changed recently in CoreFoundation)?

Comment: Broken/invalid preferences file perhaps?

Comment: @robertklep not at fault, as far as I can ascertain – and recently I have done much ascertaining of the whole codebase for that sort of easy-to-overlook issue (hence, the question post).

Comment: … in fact I noticed this problem when the test for the CLT started failing; at this point, the non-CLT tests of my AppKit cut/paste function templates are still passing, which points the finger of fault towards the `NSApplication`-specific code. (test code is here: https://github.com/fish2000/subjective-c/blob/master/tests/test_appkit_copy_paste.mm)

Comment: Too bad this question isn't answered; I'm having the exact same problem right now.